# Can we use custom UI for STRIPE

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe.js

I implemented stripe with the default interface which is all fine.

But now my client wants to use his custom screen to input payment information like this
They just want to not use STRIPE's default UI

[image]

I have be searching about it but could not find about it. Is this possible?
Please guide.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can use the https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js method with Elements to achieve this. In addition, you can create your own custom HTML form with whatever data you want (metadata in the customers API) and use it that way.

To learn how to create charges: https://stripe.com/docs/api#charges

To learn how to create customers: https://stripe.com/docs/api#customers